# Change TextField underline color to gradient

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient, textfield

I'm able to change the outline color of a `TextField's` color to a solid color by using the following code:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
    ),
  ),
),
```

However, I couldn't change its color to a gradient since it only accepts color as an input. How would I change its underline color to a linear gradient in Flutter?

Comment: `class GradientBorderSide extends BorderSide {
  final List<Color> colors;

  GradientBorderSide({this.colors});

  @override
  Paint toPaint() => Paint()
      ..shader = LinearGradient(colors: colors).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 200, 0));
}`

Comment: @pskink Sorry, your answer isn't the ideal one but then this question is solved. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: simply replace `borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange)` with `borderSide: GradientBorderSide(colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.red])` - thats all

Comment: @pskink Thanks. It works but then its opacity and width becomes lower value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though, it seems that there is not a property to change underlined color to gradient color, this effect can be achieved with Stack widget,

Here is how I tried to do it:

```
body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(
            10.0,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                cursorColor: Colors.red,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: " Enter your text here",
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 15.0,
                    horizontal: 15.0,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 0.5,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                      10.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: -1,
                child: Container(
                  height: 10,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.red,
                        Colors.green,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

You can modify it according to your UI.

Output:

[image]

Second Verion with no borders :

```
body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(
            10.0,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                cursorColor: Colors.red,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: " Enter your text here",
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 15.0,
                    horizontal: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 1,
                child: Container(
                  height: 3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.red,
                        Colors.green,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is almost close to the ideal answer but how do you change the color of the bottom border into a gradient? I am not using any border for the textfield. Its just a normal textfield. I only need to change the underline of the textfield,

Comment: Yes, but the  there is no rounded boder outside