# Is it possible to use a gradient on a TextField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm tryng to use a gradient on a textfield border but without sucess. is it possible?

```
    Widget _passwordTF() {
  return TextField(
    obscureText: true,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: LinearGradient(colors: [color1, color2]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

it says "The argument type 'LinearGradient' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395641/outlined-transparent-button-with-gradient-border-in-flutter

Comment: possible answer (and duplicate) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998027/change-textfield-underline-color-to-gradient

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Container for LinearGradient,

```
return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topRight,
        end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        stops: [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9],
        colors: [color1, color2]
      ),
    ),
    child: TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package
https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_borders
It will help to get gradient border